# Pandas: converting .xlsx file to .csv results in a zip file

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I am using pandas to covert .xlsx file to .csv. The problem is anytime I run the program the resulting file becomes a zip file instead of csv file.
This is my code:

```
 def exl2csv(x,y):
    exlfilename = str(x)
    exlsheetname = str(y)
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(exlfilename)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(exlsheetname)
    csvfileloc = os.path.join('uploads', 'frmxl2csv-' + get_random_id())
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(worksheet)
    dataframe.to_csv(csvfileloc, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
    return csvfileloc
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Pandas will infer you want compression if `.zip` is the extension of the filename. Could you print `csvfileloc` just before you save to csv to make sure `get_random_id` doesn't return a `.zip` extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pandas to do the whole thing if you'd like.

`pandas.read_excel()` will allow you to specify the sheet you want to read so you could do:

```
def exl2csv(x,y):
    exlfilename = str(x)
    exlsheetname = str(y)
    df = pandas.read_excel(exlfilename, exlsheetname)
    csvfileloc = os.path.join('uploads', 'frmxl2csv-' + get_random_id()+'.csv')
    df.to_csv(csvfileloc, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
    return csvfileloc
```

Make sure you pass in '.csv' at the end of the filename for the csv.